# How can I add a voiceover to my Keynote presentation?

Tags: macos, keynote, voiceover

I have a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.9.4 and Keynote 6.2.2.  I have a presentation done in Keynote with slide and music.  Now I want add a voice over.  Can I do that and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Play** → **Record Slideshow** and click the **Record** button at the bottom to begin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use QuickTime Player to record the audio separately, in case you want to edit it, add pauses, etc. QTP is actually a pretty versatile tool; it can do screencasting and general recording but most people don't even know it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Keynote 12.0 (and perhaps some previous version(s)):

In the Keynote menubar: Insert > Record Audio